# Add radio buttons for each row of an tableOuput

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button

I am new to shiny and i would like to add a set of radiobuttons for each row of a tableoutput. Any help would be deeply appreciated, here is my code

```
   library(shiny)
```

ui = fluidPage(

tableOutput("classification"),
  radioButtons("radio_year_select","Year", c("1999" = "1999", "2001" = "2001","2002" = "2002"), inline=T)
    )

server = function(input, output, session) {

sum_fred = reactive({

```
temp = data.frame(apply(iris,2, function(x) length(unique(x))))
temp$variable = colnames(iris)
temp$Type = lapply(iris, function(x) class(x))

colnames(temp)[1] = "Frequencies"
temp = temp[,c(2,3,1)]
```

})

output$classification = renderTable({sum_fred()})

}


 shinyApp(ui, server)

Comment: What do you want to achieve in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Here is exactly what You are looking for: [radioButtons in DT](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-radio/)

Comment: Thank you but I already found this solution but i wanted to create the radiobuttons not in Html moreover this solution doesn't work and i think the problem comes from the fact that my data is stored in a reactive()